# Sum of squares of random variables is almost surely finite

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, almost-everywhere

Let $\{X_n,n\geq 1\}$ be a sequence of random variables, with the property that $\sum_n \pm_n X_n$ converges a.s. for any choice of $\pm$. I wish to show that $\sum_n X_n^2<\infty$ a.s. (This is exercise 7.7.5 from Resnick's *A Probability Path*.)

---

The idea I have in mind is to find a countable number of sequences $\{b_n^k,n\geq 1\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ with $b_n^k\in\{-1,1\}$ for all $n,k$, and define $S_k=\{\omega:\sum_n b_n^kX_n(\omega)\text{ converges}\}$. Hopefully for this choice of sequences, $\{\sum_n X_n^2<\infty\}\supseteq \cap_k S_k$, which will prove the result.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find such a sequence. Any hints or alternative strategies would be appreciated.

Comment: The sequence of |Xn| values will, at SOME point become less than 1 (since it converges), by ratio test.  The remaining series of |Xn| must be greater than the same series of Xn^2.

Comment: @AndrewGray It is not true that $\sum_n |X_n|$ must converge a.s. For example, let $\{X_n\}$ be independent with $\Pr (X_n=1/n)=\Pr (X_n=-1/n)=1/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author gives the following hint:

> Hint:   Consider $B_n(t)X_n(\omega)$  where the random variables $\{B_n\}_{n\geqslant    1}$ are
>    coin  tossing or
>    Bernoulli  random  variables. Apply  Fubini  on   the space
>     of $(t,\omega )$.

Indeed, the main difficulty lies on the fact that we know that for any $\varepsilon= \left(\varepsilon_n\right)\in\{-1,1\}^n$, there exists $\Omega_\varepsilon$ such that $\mathbb P\left(\Omega_\varepsilon\right)=1$ and for all $\omega\in\Omega_\varepsilon$, the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\varepsilon_n X_n\left(\omega\right)$ converges. But it is not clear whether we can find $\widetilde\Omega$ of probability one which works for *any* choice of sequences.

Denote $\left(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathbb P\right)$ the original probability space. On an other probability space $\left(\Omega',\mathcal A',\mathbb P'\right)$, we consider a sequence of independent identically distributed random variables $\left(B_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ such that $\mathbb P'\left(B_n=1\right)=\mathbb P'\left(B_n=-1\right)=1/2$. Denote 
$$E:=\left\{\left(\omega,\omega'\right): \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n\left(\omega'\right)X_n\left(\omega \right)\mbox{ does not converge}                           \right\}.$$
Now appling Fubini's theorem to the indicator function of $E$, we get the existence of $\Omega_0\subset\Omega  $ such that $\mathbb P\left(\Omega_0\right)=1$ and for all $\omega\in\Omega_0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n\left(\omega'\right)X_n\left(\omega\right)$ converges for almost every $\omega\in\Omega'$. Now, use the three series theorem to show that if for some deterministic sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$, the        $\sum_n a_nB_n\left(\omega'\right)$ converges for almost every $\omega\in\Omega'$, then $\sum_n a_n^2$ is finite.

Comment: Thanks! We have
\begin{align*}
\Pr(E)&=\int_{\Omega\times\Omega'}1_E(\omega,\omega')\Bbb P\times\Bbb P'd(\omega,\omega')\\&=\int_{\Omega'}\left(\int_\Omega 1_{\{\omega:\sum_1^\infty B_n(\omega')X_n(\omega)\text{ diveges}\}}(\omega)\Bbb P(d\omega)\right)\Bbb P'(d\omega')=0
\end{align*}
where the second equality follows by Fubini.

Comment: Now let $\Omega_0=\{\omega\in\Omega:(\omega,\omega')\in E^c\text{ for }\Bbb P'\text{-almost all }\omega'\}$, then $\Bbb P(\Omega_0)=1$, since otherwise $\Pr(E^c)<1$. For $\omega\in\Omega_0$, $X_n(\omega)$ must converge to $0$, since otherwise $\sum_n X_n(\omega)B_n(\omega')$ converges for no $\omega'$. Now $X_n(\omega)$ is a convergent sequence of reals, so $X_n(\omega)B_n$ is an independent bounded sequence of random variables on $(\Omega',\mathcal{A}',\Bbb P')$. By the Kolmogorov three series theorem, $\sum_n X_n^2(\omega)=\sum_n \mathrm{Var}(X_n(\omega)B_n)<\infty$. Does that look right?